# ACL information for connecting rest services

Tags: acl, oracle-rest-data-services, oracle-apex-20.2, restdatasource

I am new to Oracle APEX, i am trying to create Rest Data Source in Oracle APEX but i am getting an error which is attached screenshot,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I1Cm.png)

So i have checked with my DBA, he want some information like below.

ACL Name:
lower port:
upper port:

SO can anyone know about the ACL name, for grant connect access to create the rest data source from APEX Application and how to find lower port and upper port for particular schema.

Thanks & Regards,
Yokeswaran G